# I can't see my dedicated graphics information in system details

Tags: nvidia, gpu, switchable-graphics

I have HP notebook da0077tx. It has 2 GB Nvidia GeForce dedicated graphics. 
I have installed Nvidia driver, it shows that nvidia is in use

[image]

But it's not showing in system details

[image]